# idapython - Determine if item is code or data

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, python, disassemblers

I need to determine whether an IDA's item is code or data.
Sometimes, data resides in an executable's code section (virtual functions tables, switch tables and stuff).
So in IDA, you can sometimes see this stuff in the code section:

```
.text:100A1424     aInternetfreepr db 'InternetFreeProxyInfoList',0
.text:100A1424                                             ; DATA XREF: .text:10038688o
.text:100A143E                     align 10h
.text:100A1440     aInternetfreeco db 'InternetFreeCookies',0 ; DATA XREF: .text:10038680o
.text:100A1454     aInternetfortez db 'InternetFortezzaCommand',0
.text:100A1454                                             ; DATA XREF: .text:10038678o
```

is there a method I can call to defer between code and data using only the EA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IDA utilizes flags for checking the properties of locations.

Looking at the [API](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/) you can use `GetFlags(ea)` and pass its output to `isCode(flags)` to check if a location is *flagged* as being code.

You can find the exact definitions of the flags in `IDC.IDC`. A small excerpt:

```
#define isCode(F)       ((F & MS_CLS) == FF_CODE) // is code byte?
#define isData(F)       ((F & MS_CLS) == FF_DATA) // is data byte?
#define isTail(F)       ((F & MS_CLS) == FF_TAIL) // is tail byte?
#define isUnknown(F)    ((F & MS_CLS) == FF_UNK)  // is unexplored byte?
#define isHead(F)       ((F & FF_DATA) != 0)      // is start of code/data?
```

You can use this from Python like so:

```
ea = ScreenEA()
flags = GetFlags(ea)

if isData(flags):
    print("It's data!")

elif isCode(flags):
    print("It's code!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, you can use [Sark](http://sark.rtfd.io) to get it done:

```
import sark

# For current line
sark.Line().is_code

# For specific line
sark.Line(ea).is_code
```

Note: I am the creator of Sark.

Comment: Sark is a great and well written library. However, it is much slower than using the "native" IDAPython functions (the speed using Sark was unbearable and improved significantly after rewriting some of its functionality)

Comment: The performance is indeed an issue. I still prefer it in most cases as it easier to write in, and performance can be improved later by replacing the relevant code.

Comment: Well said. I'm enjoying much of your code projects, keep going bro

Comment: I don't want this come off as being rude, but it is good etiquette and a SE *requirement* to fully disclose your affiliation to solutions you advertise in your answers. See  http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/behavior/